# Disable downloads in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, kiosk-mode

I am using google chrome in kiosk mode. Everything is working fine. But I dont want users to download files when the click on the download link. Does the chrome extension API support this?
Bonus question: Is it possible to restrict users in a fixed directory when uploading file( I mean in an upload dialog)?

Comment: There's no reliable way to do this. You can use the `webRequest` API to disable remote downloads, but that doesn't catch script-generated content or data-URLs.

Comment: This is an interesting use case that the team might have intended to address in a later version of kiosk mode. Today they intended kiosk mode to run a single Chrome packaged app, where the app developer can control the experience completely and avoid having download links in the content the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable downloads within chrome, but some operating systems offer ways to do it with a software like parental controls. Maybe you could look into that.